# how to assign a fixed port to local plumber server

Tags: r, plumber

I have set up a local plumber server in R which I like to call locally from Excel VBA.
After a restart of the R plumber-code a new portnumber is assigned. This means I have to adapt my Excel VBA code manually every time with a new port number. For that reason I would like to assign a fixed portnumber. I did find this solution:

```
@options(plumber.port = XYZ)
```

Although when I integrate this line in my code below I receive the error:

```
Error in stopOnLine(lineNum, line, "No path specified.") : 
  Error on line #10: '#* @options(plumber.port = 5555)' - No path specified.
```

code:

```
#plumber.R
library(plumber)
#* @get /random_numbers
#* @param maxn
function(maxn) {
  maxn<-as.numeric(maxn)
  runif(1,min=0,max=maxn)
}

#* @options(plumber.port = 5555)
#* @post /operation
#* @param numbers vector of numbers
#* @param metric
function(numbers, metric) {
  if(metric == 'mean')
    mean(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'sd')
    sd(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'min')
    min(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'max')
    max(numbers)
  else
    "Wrong metric! use mean, sd, min or max"
}
```

I have tried `plumber.port = 127.0.0.1:5555` although this makes no difference.
Is there a way to assign a fixed adres to the plumber server?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The web page for `plumber` (https://www.rplumber.io/) shows this syntax:  `pr("plumber.R") %>% pr_run(port=8000)`.  Does that work for you?

Comment: @user2554330 thank you. This is a solution, although i would have a slight preference to assign the portnumber in the original code since with this solution i have a separate part of code which calls the original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on this is confusing and I had to look for example usage on github to figure it out. Rather than `#* @options(plumber.port = 5555)` you need to use `options("plumber.port" = 5555)`

```
#plumber.R
library(plumber)
options("plumber.port" = 5555)
#* @get /random_numbers
#* @param maxn
function(maxn) {
  maxn<-as.numeric(maxn)
  runif(1,min=0,max=maxn)
}

#* @post /operation
#* @param numbers vector of numbers
#* @param metric
function(numbers, metric) {
  if(metric == 'mean')
    mean(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'sd')
    sd(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'min')
    min(numbers)
  else if(metric == 'max')
    max(numbers)
  else
    "Wrong metric! use mean, sd, min or max"
}
```

But as @user2554330 pointed out, I usually set the port in the `pr_run` function instead.